# Any ideas how can I export schemas of all the django model's inside a django project into an external format?

Tags: python, django, operating-system, filesystems

I got a requirement from my manager that they require a generic python script that export schemas of all the model present in the django project into excel. Generic because we want to do the same for multiple microservices running on django in our company. Each row in excel is supposed to contain infromation about field in that model. Each model is supposed to be represented in new sheet. I can't seem to figure out what would be a good way to do this.

One approach I can think of is using recursion to iterate inside all the files inside the codebase and look for files names like models.py and iterate inside of them to find different classes and extract info like field type, constraints, max length/size, nullable or not, etc. but not sure if this would be a good approach because edge case handling would be hard in the case I think.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let django do the heavy lifting of handling apps and models for you:

```
from pathlib import Path

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings


project_root = Path(settings.BASE_DIR)

# Loop through all apps
for app_name, app_conf in sorted(apps.app_configs.items()):

    # Local app within project_root?
    try:
        Path(app_conf.path).relative_to(project_root)
    except ValueError:
        # Not a local app => skip
        continue

    # Loop through all models of app_name
    for model_name, model_cls in sorted(apps.all_models[app_name].items()):
        print(f'App: {app_name:<25s} Model: {model_name}')

        # Now work with the model ..
        #  .. create documentation
        #  .. export documentation
```

This should give you a start for your task.